# Pushing Firestore document IDs to array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

i am fairly new to Vuejs and Firestore, currently working on my first bigger project. I have 1 collection in my firestore with 3 documents. I am trying to retrieve the document ids and save them to an array.
My component for this looks like this:

```
<template>
  <div class="main">
    <button @click="getIds" class="nextBtn">Next</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { computed } from 'vue';
import { useStore } from 'vuex'

export default {

setup() {
  const store = useStore();
  const questdb = computed(() => store.state.questdb);
  let idArray = [];

  function getIds() {
    this.questdb.onSnapshot(function(doc) {      
      doc.forEach(doc => {
        try{
          this.idArray.push(doc.id);
        }
        catch(error) {
        console.log("Error: ", error);
        }              
      })
    })
  }
  return {
    store,
    questdb,
    idArray,
    getIds
  }
},
  methods: {
  }
}
</script>
```

The error I am getting is following:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

When I just `console.log()` the document ids, it works fine.

I guess the problem is, that those data just can not simply be pushed into an array or I am lacking some basic understanding on how to retrieve data from a firestore.

Comment: Did you define `idArray` somewhere? Please add more complete code.

Comment: Also this function, where does it live? In the `methods` section?

Comment: Yes I did, added it to the top.
I had the function in the methods section before but moved it to the "setup()" section and return its name.

Comment: Can we get the whole component? This doesn't really help. If it would be plain javascript `this.idArray` should be just `idArray`. But since it's a vue component (I assume) it could be different.

Comment: Added the whole component now

Comment: remove `this` keyword from `this.idArray`

Comment: I would really recommend you to go through the vue tutorial to get the basics down. Here is some advice on how to tackle this problem:

The script section of Vue is divided in a few different keys. In this case you want to use `created` (instead of `setup()`), `methods` (to define your `getIds()` function) and `data` (to store the array of ids). Reference: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/data-methods.html#data-properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for 'this' before idArray, 'this' doesn't contain an idArray so the result is 'undefined'. Try it in this way.

```
function getIds() {
this.questdb.onSnapshot(function(doc) {      
  doc.forEach(doc => {
    try{
      idArray.push(doc.id);
    }
    catch(error) {
    console.log("Error: ", error);
    }              
  })
})
```

}

Check the Vue composition API doc for more info.
https://v3.vuejs.org/api/composition-api.html#setup